# Create array with dotdict

Tags: python

I am using a dotdict in my app:

```
class dotdict(dict):
    """dot.notation access to dictionary attributes"""
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

This works:

```
test = dotdict({})
test.foo = "bar"
```

However, this doesn't work as i get `'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`:

```
test = dotdict({})
test.foo[0] = "bar"
```

I would like to know if there is a way to change **setattr** to automatically create an array of a certain size so that I don't get an error? Thank you

Comment: Use defaultdict ?

Comment: `test.foo[0] = "bar"` first evaluates `test.foo` which calls `__getattr__`, not `__setattr__`.